# CSRs generated from CloudHSM EC key fail verification

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl

I'm looking to use CloudHSM for an intermediate CA. To that end, I need to generate a keypair and sign it with the root (offline HSM) CA. We're using ECDSA.

However, when I generate a CSR from an ECC keypair, it fails verification. Here's what I'm doing:

```
genECCKeyPair -i 2 -l intermediate-ca -nex
getCaviumPrivKey -k 42 -out intermediate-ca.key
```

```
openssl req -engine cloudhsm -new -key intermediate-ca.key -out intermediate-ca.csr -subj "/CN=Intermediate CA"
```

```
openssl req -in intermediate-ca.csr -verify -noout
```

This reports:

```
verify failure
139822323439520:error:0D0C5006:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:EVP lib:a_verify.c:249:
```

If I attempt to sign the CSR, openssl reports `Signature did not match the certificate request`

If I do the same steps with an RSA key, everything's fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSSL engine for CloudHSM doesn't support ECC keys.

This is stated implicitly by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/openssl-library.html (it's not in the list).

What confused me is that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/ki-openssl-sdk.html#ki-openssl-4 implies that it *is* supported.

It's not. Use one of the other client libraries (JCE, PKCS#11, KSP or CNG).

(I confirmed this with AWS support)